# How can I see if an x and y are on the edge or inside of the rectangle? How to define my method contains point?

Tags: python

How can I see if an x and y are on the edge or inside of the rectangle? Does anyone have any ideas of how to go about that?
I have tried to create a method that will do this called contains point but I am sure I have done this incorrectly

my code:

```
class Rectangle:   # creates class Rectangle

    def __init__(self, rX, rY, rW, rH):  # initialized so we can call our variables
        self.x = rX  # x coord
        self.y = rY  # y coord
        self.w = rW  # width
        self.h = rH  # heigh

    def __str__(self):  # will return string
        return 'Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')'

    def right(self):  # will check right edge
        return self.x + self.w  # returns right edge

    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.h

    def size(self):  # Method Size will obtain size of rectangle
        return self.w, self.h

    def position(self):  # Method will show coords
        return self.x, self.y

    def area(self):  # method will return area of rectangle
        return self.w * self.h

    def expand(self, offset):  # expand will take in an offset value and apply it to a new rectangle
        newX = self.x - offset
        newY = self.y - offset
        newW = self.w + (offset * 2)
        newH = self.h + (offset * 2)

        newRectangle = Rectangle(newX, newY, newW, newH)
        return newRectangle

    def contains_point(self, x, y):      # contains point will take in 2 coords
                                         # and check to see if they are in the rectangle
        if x <= self.x and y <= self.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False


r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
print(r.expand(-5), r)
print(r.contains_point(0, 0))
```

Comment: If you're using Jython, look at java.awt.Rectangle and the getBounds method

Answer (score 1):

If you have x1, x2 and y1, y2 defining the outer corners of your rectangle, then you can test a point.x, point.y by checking if point.x is between x1 and x2, and point.y is between y1 and y2.

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_point(self, x, y):      # contains point will take in 2 coords
                                     # and check to see if they are in the rectangle
    if (self.x <= x <= self.right()  and
        self.y <= y <= self.bottom()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The `range` version is horribly inefficient, and the other version has a typo in `x >= self.y`.

Comment: I know but i think for a beginner the `range` is quite simple to understand. (Typo corrected)

Comment: The `range` will also not work. It will check if x is a member of the list  `[self.x, self.x+1, self.x+2, ..., self.right]`. It will not return true e.g. if `x` equals `self.x+0.1`, though it should clearly return true in this case. You're obviously being mislead by the `range` wording...

Comment: This cant be right because if I check 30,40 it returns false those would be right on the line, am i right?

Comment: It's working for me. with 
`r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
print r.contains_point(30,40)`